# Creating HTML Report using ReportNG

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I'm using Webdriver with Eclipse TestNG. I want to generate html report using ReportNG, but I think I'm missing something that's why the report is not generating.

Please look at the steps I followed to gererate report:

1) I already created many TestNG classes for my project and they are present in testng.xml. I simply added the listeners

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>   
   <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM
   "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">  
   <suite name="Test"
    parallel="none">   
   <listeners>
   <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter" />
   <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter" />   
   </listeners>   <test name="Test">     <classes>
   <class name="test.Reports"/>
   <class name="test.System"/>
   <class name=".firstClass"/>
   </classes>   </test> <!-- Test -->   </suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

2) I added the reportingng.jar and velocity.jar in Project's External jar files

3) I disabled the default listeners

4) I don't know how to add following jars in .classpath and how to get .classpath file

classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/velocity-dep-1.x.jar

classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/testng-6.x.jar"

classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/reportng-1.1.x.jar"

When I run as Suite 'tentng.xml' (one present in Project), it says:

```
     org.testng.TestNGException: 
     Cannot find class in classpath: .firstClass
   at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:81)
   at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:73)
   at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:59)
   at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:543
```